# SharePoint 2013 search result web part not showing all result

Tags: search, sharepoint-2013, sharepoint-search

I add the standard search result web part to an empty page layout. I click "change query", and add the query I want. The search result preview shows 179 results. Perfect, just what I wanted. I click "OK", "Apply", and publish the page. Now it only shows 7 results. I haven't configured nothing else on the search result web part.

Where did the remaining 172 results go? Any suggestions are appreciated :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj687488.aspx

I had the same issue, it turned out that Search Results web part was incorrectly trimming results that were considered duplicates.

I fixed this by setting **TrimDuplicates** to *false*.  To do this:

- Export the web part,
- change **TrimDuplicates** to *false* in the **DataProviderJSON** property, and
- add the web part back to your page.

Hope that helps
Christopher Scolt

Comment: Thank you for this.  We were expending a lot of effort trying to figure out why we were getting one search result.   It didn't even cross my mind.

Comment: Surprisingly, this resolved the issue I was facing with the crawl log warning "This item was truncated because the parsed output was greater than the maximum number of allowed characters" - I guess the truncated data was "identical" enough to be thrown out of the search results display.

Answer (score 0):

Believing its a content search webpart, take a look at this [blog](http://www.wonderlaura.com/Lists/Posts/Post.aspx?ID=185)

In it the author mentioned something like, You can set up the default number of items to show in the web part.
Hope this helps

Comment: It wouldn't be. There are two web parts. One that's meant for enterprise search and one that's meant to be content roll-up. I'm pretty sure he means the Search Results Web Part. I'm having almost the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

This might be the result collapsing removing your results.

You can test it using the REST API and setting the CollapseSpecification.

To change it in the search GUI, you have to export the Search Results webpart, edit the xml and upload the xml under Add web parts. The webpart will show up under "Imported Webparts". Add the webpart, and re-connect the searchbox and refiner webpart to your new search result web part (you need to do this even though you remove the old webpart). After this it will work, but don't change any settings on the web part in the GUI, then the settings will be overwritten.

Comment: What is the web part called and what did you edit in the XML?

Answer (score 0):

I've seen this when you're using a  `'`  in the query template rather than a `"` to frame your strings. (  `field1:"match this"`   vs   `field1:'match this'` )   The query builder gives results however when embedded into a webpart or page snippet, we get no results.   Mine were embedded into the page as a snippet webpart and when I looked at the debugger I can see some webparts were using `"`  which got converted to `\&amp;quot;`     whereas the ones that didn't work became some Unicode equivalent like `\u00`....

Changing the webpart snippet to use `\&amp;quot;`  worked perfectly.